# Unity2D, how i show the ICON Image on the GUI.Label in the list?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I had trying to read most of the similar post on internet, but i still lost for that. So i hope any one can give me some guideline for that. thanks a lots! i want to show the ICON on the list, and the ICON list is constant images. how i can call the file? the project i doing is 2D and i just want to show the ICON on GUI. For additional information, i just trying to use programming way to call out the image, but fail. Below code is the original code before i implement the images code.

```
GUILayout.BeginVertical ("box");
            GUILayout.Label ("Staff");
            int maxHeight = 15;
            int maxHeightRange = maxHeight * 35;
            scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(new Rect(50, 25, 400, 175), scrollPosition, new Rect(0, 0, 200, maxHeightRange));
            for(int i = 0; i < maxHeight; i++)
            {
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal ("box");
                GUILayout.Label ("first");
                GUILayout.Label (i.ToString());
                GUILayout.Label ("satu");
                GUILayout.Label ("icon"); //Icon i want to show is here.
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
            }
            GUI.EndScrollView();
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace ();
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Exit Shrink Fade")) {
                LzTbStaff.exitShrinkFade (0.25f);
                LzShwStaff = false;
                print("xxx");
            }
            GUILayout.EndVertical ();
```

and the part i add on this below.

```
Texture iconsample;
            iconsample = (Texture)Resources.Load("iconsample.jpg");
                GUILayout.Label (iconsample,GUILayout.Width(30));
```

Comment: GUI.DrawTexture... Search in google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar case in my game, I wanted to show a country flag based on player country in the highscore page using GUI, so I had a folder in "Assets/Resources/Flags" with all the countries codes (example: br.png, us.png, jp.png, kr.png, etc).

The function Resources.Load() only works with assets inside the folder "Assets/Resources", and the name must be just the file name without extension.

Example:

```
Texture2D myTexture = Resources.Load("Flags/br") as Texture2D;
```

And my code used in my project:

```
Texture2D myTexture = Resources.Load("Flags/" + scoreRow.ISOCountryCode.ToLower()) as Texture2D;
if (myTexture != null)
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(marginRight, marginTop, lineWidth, lineHeight), myTexture);
}
else
{
    //Debug.Log("invalid flag: " + scoreRow.ISOCountryCode);
}
```

With the Texture2D you can Draw to the screen using GUI.DrawTexture().

Answer (score 0):

```
Texture2D iconsample;
            //iconsample = (Texture)Resources.Load("iconsample.jpg");
            iconsample = Resources.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Textures/UI/Resources/iconsample.jpg",typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it a little by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?